# Aplicar filtro dinâmico num dataframe dinâmico no Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filtro, dataframe

**TL;DR**

Alguém sabe como aplico um filtro que fará a soma dos valores de uma coluna de uma tabela dinâmica?

**O problema**

Bom, vou mostrar o DataFrame primeiro, será mais fácil de explicar.

```
dados = ["Cidade_a",2,'-'],
        ["Cidade_b",5,7],
        ["Cidade_c",'X',9]

df = pd.DataFrame(dados, columns=['Nome', 'var_1', 'var_2'])
```

O que vai gerar o seguinte DF:

```
Nome       var_1 var_2
Cidade_a    2    '-'
Cidade_b    5     7
Cidade_c   'X'    9
```

Eu preciso criar um total, abaixo dessas lista abaixo dessas informações, porém, ignorando os valores "X" e "-". Ou seja, a soma para a `var_1` ser `7` e a soma para `var_2` ser `16`.

Se fosse só isso, não seria problema, acontece que eu preciso fazer essa mesma tarefa com outras tabelas, são mais de 10 tabelas e pode ser que aumente nos próximos dias. Assim como, cada tabela tem um tamanho diferente em questões de colunas.

**O que eu já tentei**

Eu fiz um drop da coluna `Nome`. E tentei criar um dicionário dinâmico para incluir os valores, mas na hora de alterar quais colunas o Pandas deveria verificar, ele dá erro, diz que não encontrou a coluna com o nome `coluna`, invés de achar a coluna `var_1` e `var_2`. Esse foi o código que usei. Baseado nisso, eu jogaria numa função que seria aplicado em todas as tabelas que eu trabalho.

```
valor = dict()

for coluna in colunas:
    
    valor[coluna] = tabela[(tabela.coluna != 'X') & (tabela.coluna != '-')][coluna].sum()
```

Com o resultado disso, era só incluir no dataframe que eu estivesse manipulando com um:

`df[len(df)] = valor`

Já pensei em fazer isso na planilha geral, e depois "recortar" as colunas que eu quero com os dados já inclusos, mas aí teria que adicionar mais de 100 linhas de código para cada coluna que existe na planilha completa.

Aceito sugestões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se é bem isso que vc quer, mas veja se lhe ajuda.

Primeiro tem uma função que cria um outro dataframe com os totais

```
def total(tabela):
    valor = {"Nome": "Total"}

    for coluna in tabela.columns:
        if coluna != "Nome":
            valor[coluna] = tabela[(tabela[coluna] != 'X') & (tabela[coluna] != '-')][coluna].sum()
    
    valor = pd.DataFrame(valor, index=[len(tabela)])   
    
    return valor
```

Depois vc concatena esse novo dataframe com o antigo:

```
total = total(df)
df = pd.concat([df, total])
```

Ai você terá uma saída assim:

```
    Nome    var_1   var_2
0   Cidade_a    2   "-"
1   Cidade_b    5    7
2   Cidade_c   "X"   9
3   Total       7    16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[len(df)] = np.insert('Total', 1, df.drop('Nome', 1).replace('X|-', 0, regex=True).sum(0))
```

Comment: Explique melhor sua resposta.

Comment: Isso é um pedido?

Comment: Sua resposta funcionou tanto quanto a outra, porém, eu teria um pouco mais de dificuldade caso fosse preciso fazer alguma alteração no código. Mas funcionou.

Comment: Esse código privilegia o tratamento dos valores excepcionais, que parece ser o seu maior problema. Na outra resposta, você teria que fazer uma nova condição `(tabela[coluna] != '<valor>')` cada vez que surgisse um dado não inteiro diferente. Nessa daqui, você só adiciona à regex `'X|-|<valor>'`.